# Flask-SqlAlchemy insert extremely slow after load large amount of data

Tags: python, performance, flask, sqlalchemy

I have  a table with about 200k records. I'm trying to insert abount 20 records in batch with Flask-SqlAlchemy. It takes about 20ms normally, but when I load all the records from the table before insertion, it takes about 1000ms(50x slower). Why?

```
from models import LocationMap, db
import random
import time
# the last line 'db.session.commit()' will be extremely slow when I uncomment this line.
#known_locations = LocationMap.query.all()
for i in range(10):
    loc = LocationMap()
    loc.longitude = 0 #location_batch[i + j][0]
    loc.latitude = random.random() #location_batch[i + j][1]
    loc.country = 'test'
    loc.province = 'test2'
    loc.city = 'test3'
    loc.district = 'test4'
    loc.township = 'test5'
    db.session.add(loc)

st = time.time()
db.session.commit()
print(time.time() - st)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with tracking / state of instances, references, identity map etc. In other words - I think the reason is mainly how similar `ORM`'s work (`sqlalchemy` is not tiny `ORM`). This is why these types of tools are inferior in performance when working with large datasets. But they have very powerful functionality.

I will try to explain with an example:

```
locations = LocationMap.query.all()
locations[0].country = 'new value1'
locations[1].country = 'new value2'
for i in range(10):
    # ... db.session.add(loc)

db.session.commit()
```

What's going to happen? Yes - we will have not only inserts. We will also have 2 updates(`new value1`, `new value2`). Because `Session` has a references to all objects. And now let's try to remove selected instances from a `Session`:

```
locations = LocationMap.query.all()
db.session.expunge_all()
# your code here... for i in range(10):
```

You'll see that operation takes ~20ms(normal time). Also you can remove specific object from a `Session`:

```
locations = LocationMap.query.all()
for l in locations:
    # if we don't need reference anymore
    db.session.expunge(l)
```

Otherwise, you can say no to `ORM` if performance is critical to you.

Comment: Thank you very much. `db.session.expunge_all()` works very well.